# How are the very first telomeres added?

Tags: molecular-biology, dna, molecular-genetics

Here is an image of telomerase adding telomerase.

[image: telomerase function]

As we can see, the telomerase sort of binds to a bit of the existing "3' flanking end of [the] telomere" - it's almost half and half.

My question is, where did that existing telomere come from? And the telomere before that?

Essentially, the telomeres must have *begun* from some point on the chromosome/DNA, but how were *those* telomeres added if the telomerase has a preset RNA sequence that it uses to bind to specific nucleotide bases? Does our human DNA coincidentally end with TTAGGG as well or something?

Comment: See [telomerase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telomerase) and [TERT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telomerase_reverse_transcriptase).

Comment: So I understand that it has to use reverse transcription to do it, but I cannot find anything specific to telomerase adding the first telomeres. Any help?

Comment: I won't be able to help you, as I know little about molecular genetics. But given the number of upvotes, you will probably get the attention of someone who will be able to answer such as Chris or WYSIWYG.

Comment: Telomere might have evolved from a retrotransposos. http://www.nature.com/scitable/content/t-loops-and-the-origin-of-telomeres-26791

Answer (score 1):

Telomeres are maintained by telomerase (in certain cell types, not all of them) at every replication. So, the answer to your questions *"where did that existing telomere come from? And the telomere before that?"* is: "because there was already a telomere to extend at the end of this chromosome".

Your questions boil down to *"how did telomeres appear in the first place?"* (because once telomeres and a maintenance mechanism have been established, they will simply remain unless some major genomic catastrophe happens), and this is a difficult question. As [Whitney](https://biology.stackexchange.com/users/27415/whitney) pointed out in the comments of your question, some hypotheses about the origin of telomeres are discussed in [this article](http://www.nature.com/scitable/content/t-loops-and-the-origin-of-telomeres-26791).
Interestingly, *Drosophila* doesn't have telomerase, and maintains telomeres by a transposition mechanism. Somehow this is a clue about how telomeres appeared: *Drosophila* telomeres could be an intermediate between circular chromosomes and telomerase-based maintenance of linear chromosomes.

This is a complicated topic, but the scientific literature about the appearance of telomeres is fascinating. Some bacteria (*Borrelia* and *Streptomyces* taxa) have linear chromosomes, but maintenance mechanisms that have nothing to do with transposition nor telomerase.

Here are some references:

- *Drosophila*: https://doi.org/10.3389/fonc.2013.00112
- *Borrelia*: https://doi.org/10.1146/annurev.micro.112408.134037
- *Streptomyces*: http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/7171_2007_090

If you can read French, you will find more info in the introduction of [my PhD thesis](https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-01281310).